# How to Prepare data for D3 collapsible tree chart using CSV file

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to reproduce the D3 collapsible tree. Please find the link to the collapsible tree which I am trying to reproduce.

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Attached image shows how the data looks like in the CSV file.

[CSV Data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXpER.png)

Does anyone has experience in creating the collapsible tree with this type of data format?

Does any

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to write a script to convert your CSV into the same JSON format Mike Bostock had. The underlying data for his chart looks like the following.

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/flare.json

Comment: I am pretty new to Javascript and D3. My csv file has more than 1000 records of data and I don't want to manually create the parent and child hierarchy. Is there a way to automate?